# Application building using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create an application that allow students to see the list of mandatory and elective courses  using def key word in tkinter. This is the error i get after running the code.

Exception in Tkinter callback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mhm01\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mhm01\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13464\560191512.py", line 25, in courses
    label3.configure(courses)
  File "C:\Users\mhm01\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\mhm01\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1635, in _configure
    return self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))
  File "C:\Users\mhm01\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1623, in _getconfigure1
    x = self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(*args))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a key in the `courses` dictionary variable which is an invalid input to the `.configure()` method of the label class of tkinter - according to the error it looks like you have a key in `courses` called `-`. Try removing that (and ensure you only have valid keys in the dictionary you pass to configure)

Comment: `-` is probably added by tkinter. However you are right in your conclusion that there is no valid *keyword* parsed to configure. It's also possible that's an empty dictionary or empty string parsed. (Didn't test it though)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
label3.configure(courses)
```

to:

```
label3.configure(text=courses)
```